# Not using all python sys.argv

Tags: python-3.x

New to python, but my question is about sys.argv.

I have program that I want to execute different sets of code depending on how many arguments are passed to it.

python test.py hello awesome world

would run a different set of code from

python test.py hello world

If I define 3 sys.argv then it is expecting 3 arguments every time otherwise I get: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your code and what exactly are you trying to do, and where is it failing, and exactly how?

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv will explain how to use arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in if statements:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
   #do something
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
   #do something else
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
   #do something different
else:
   #do the last possibility
```

Comment: But I want to be able to store the values of the arguments and use it in the code, so for example:
name = sys.argv[1]
age = sys.argv[2]

Comment: Yes, you can do that inside the if statements

Comment: Got it, i put the name, age  = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2] after the if statement. THANKS!